# Fetch and display dropdown selected value in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I wanted to fetch the selected value from the database and display it in codeigniter `form_dropdown()` function but it displays wrong.

Controller:

```
$type = array(
'options' => array(
  'section'       => 'Section',
  'transaction' => 'Transaction',
  'document'      => 'Document'
  ),
'attributes' => array(
  'class' => 'form-control'
  )
);
```

View:

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('type', $type['options'],'', $type['attributes']) ?>
```

The [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrIeA.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

Controller:

```
$this->data['type']  =  array(
        'name'         => 'type_value',
        'attributes'   => 'class="form-control"',
        'value'        => (isset($database_type_value) && trim($database_type_value)) ? $database_type_value: $this->input->post('type_value',TRUE),   //$database_type_value - value from database
        'options_list' => array(
            'section'        => 'Section',
            'transaction'    => 'Transaction',
            'document'       => 'Document'
        ),
);
```

View:

```
<?php echo form_dropdown($type['name'],$type['options_list'],$type['value'],$type['attributes']);?>
```

Comment: Thanks but it returns undefined variables name, option_list and value

Comment: Can you please show us the code where you load your template?

Comment: Note: it works if i use this `<?php echo form_dropdown('type', $type['options'], '', $type['attributes']) ?>` but of course doesn't show the selected value first. using my code above

Comment: I stored the field name in the 'name' parameter (`'name'         => 'type_value',`). So that all field data can be managed in the controller. Also please answer my previous comment.

Comment: Yes I get your point but I found the main problem, it's on how I load my view. I forgot to pass the $type variable. Anyways I vote your answer It is useful